# Movie about a man in a car trying to run away from a forest

Tags: story-identification, movie

Years ago, I caught a glimpse of a movie my father was watching on TV.
It was a man driving a car in the middle of a forest, on some forest road. I don't know if he was alone or with a woman.

He was in a hurry, like he was trying to escape and stopped near a tree, where the road was forking. He then carved a sign with his knife, to know that he already was here and drove off, taking the road on the right. The camera didn't move and soon the man came again from the left side. The scene happend during a day.

This is the only thing I remember from that movie. Does anybody know anything? I think the forest may have been changing to trap the man inside? Or it may have been some story about the nature taking revenge on the people.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: Hello,
It is hard for me to remember, but it may have been around 2010.
But it probably wasn't a new movie. Back in a day it took some time for movies to get to my country.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_End_(2003_film)?

Comment: I don't think thats it. This movie takes place in a night, but the scene i remember was in a day. I'll edit that in the post.

Comment: Just noting nothing I see matching in https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UnnaturallyLoopingLocation

Comment: If someone posts a correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: "Years ago" doesn't equate to 2010 in my head, that's why specifying an (approximate) time frame is important.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps *[Long Weekend](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/LongWeekend)*?

> Long Weekend is an ecologically-themed 1978 Australian psychological horror film directed by Colin Eggleston and starring John Hargreaves and Briony Behets.
>
> The story concerns a couple in a disintegrating marriage, Peter (Hargreaves) and Marcia (Behets), who, along with their dog, go for a weekend camping trip. The couple, especially Peter, take out their frustrations on the natural environment, committing such crimes against the environment as killing a dugong, throwing lit cigarette butts in dry bush, and spraying insecticide. As tensions between the couple escalate, nature is not pleased with their environmental wrongdoing and starts to strike back, first by an eagle and possum attacking Peter, and then through more insidious means.

The entry in [Going in Circles](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GoingInCircles) is where I found it:

> When Peter and Marcia are trying find Lunda Beach, Marcia's tells him they are driving in circles, as they've passed the same tree multiple times. Later, when Peter is attempting to escape he beach, he stops to refill the car's rank and drops the empty fuel can by the side of the track. He drives off, but a few minutes later her finds himself driving past the bright orange fuel can.

### Trailer

Comment: Small warning: The 2 links are entrances to the TVTropes wikihole.

Comment: Ambiguous sci-fi/fantasy nature to the film, but close enough.

Comment: That seems really close to what i had in my mind. Still im not sure becouse there is still this picture of a man craving something on the tree in my mind and not the empty fuel can, but it is the closest that i have been in years and it can be just a deformed memory of mine due to the years passing. Thank you, i will definitely watch this movie to see if it was it.

Comment: @Konkord: If you're not certain, feel free to remove approval by clicking on the checkmark again. :) Last thing we want is you leaving unsatisfied, or feeling forced to accept a wrong answer.